# What are strategies for handling a pattern with a combined move and reference without feature(move_ref_pattern) or mem::replace?

Tags: rust

Short of using the feature `#![feature(move_ref_pattern)]`, what are the strategies for handling a match with both a move and reference in the pattern?

Often, I have a routine that passes in an argument by reference and an argument by move.  I'd like to match on a tuple between them because it makes it easier for me to see the different combinations.  At the same time, I'd like to appropriately use the memory from the second argument since it's already owned by the routine.

At the moment, the way I handle it is by matching on a mutable reference and then calling `std::mem::replace` to get access to the value.  This feels clunky to me and I'd like to see if there's a better way to handle this.

The struct `F64` is used to prevent `Copy` from being called in this mostly contrived example:

```rust
// Cloneable, but not copyable float type
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum MyFloat {
    Zero,
    Num(F64),
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct F64(f64);

// Consume y, but not x
fn my_add(x: &MyFloat, mut y: MyFloat) -> MyFloat {
    match (x, &mut y) {
        (MyFloat::Zero, MyFloat::Zero) => MyFloat::Zero,
        (MyFloat::Zero, y @ MyFloat::Num(_)) => std::mem::replace(y, MyFloat::Zero),
        (MyFloat::Num(_), MyFloat::Zero) => x.clone(),
        (MyFloat::Num(x), MyFloat::Num(y)) => {
            let y = std::mem::replace(y, F64(0.));
            MyFloat::Num(my_add_driver(x, y))
        }
    }
}

fn my_add_driver(x: &F64, y: F64) -> F64 {
    F64((*x).0 + y.0)
}

// Run the program
fn main() {
    let x = MyFloat::Num(F64(1.2));
    let y = MyFloat::Num(F64(2.3));
    println!("{:?} + {:?} = {:?}", x, y.clone(), my_add(&x, y));
}
```

Here, `y` is passed into the match as a mutable reference, which solves the move-ref issue with the pattern match.  However, we have to then extract its memory using `std::mem::replace`.  Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Looks like you've found both the nice and intuitive but yet unstable way with `move_ref_pattern` and the current less nice workaround with `std::mem::replace`. It's unclear why you'd expect a 3rd way to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it slightly like this:

```rust
fn my_add(x: &MyFloat, y: MyFloat) -> MyFloat {
    // match on y by value, not by ref:
    match (x, y) {
        (MyFloat::Zero, MyFloat::Zero) => MyFloat::Zero,
        (MyFloat::Zero, y @ MyFloat::Num(_)) => y,
        (MyFloat::Num(_), MyFloat::Zero) => x.clone(),
        (MyFloat::Num(x), MyFloat::Num(ref mut y)) => {
            let y = std::mem::replace(y, F64(0.));
            MyFloat::Num(my_add_driver(x, y))
        }
    }
}
```

To get rid of the other `mem::replace()` call is only possible with the `move_ref_pattern` feature, or with a helper method similar to [`Option::as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref):

```rust
impl MyFloat {
    fn as_ref_option(&self) -> Option<&F64> {
        match self {
            MyFloat::Zero => None,
            MyFloat::Num(f) => Some(f),
        }
    }
}

// Consume y, but not x
fn my_add(x: &MyFloat, y: MyFloat) -> MyFloat {
    match (x.as_ref_option(), y) {
        (None, MyFloat::Zero) => MyFloat::Zero,
        (None, y @ MyFloat::Num(_)) => y,
        (Some(_), MyFloat::Zero) => x.clone(),
        (Some(x), MyFloat::Num(y)) => MyFloat::Num(my_add_driver(x, y)),
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f7d3d0ffca1da00a281d42b8b8ab7a3e)